# Why C static functions doesn't go to text section but to rodata section?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I define some static functions in a C source file. After compiling it, I use nm tool to display all the symbols in the .o file, and find that all of my defined static function is in the rodata section, and their symbols name are **func**.xxxx. Shouldn't the function be located in the text function?

Following is the results of nm command displaying the static functions. The 'r' before **func**.xxxx means that the function is stored in rodata section.

```
00000000 t desc_to_mattr
         U __do_panic
00000000 r __func__.5546
00000000 r __func__.5554
00000000 r __func__.5560
00000000 r __func__.5565
00000000 r __func__.5604
00000000 r __func__.5638
00000000 r __func__.5698
00000000 r __func__.5710
00000000 r __func__.5719
00000000 r __func__.5729
00000000 r __func__.5758
```

Following is my gcc option:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -std=gnu99 -Werror -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wall -Wcast-align -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wextra -Wfloat-equal -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wstrict-prototypes -Wswitch-default -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-format-zero-length -Waggregate-return -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-definition -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -Wundef -pedantic -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Os -g -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -pipe -g3 -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfloat-abi=soft -funwind-tables -mthumb -mthumb-interwork -fno-short-enums -fno-common -mno-unaligned-access -MD -MF
```

Comment: @M.M Are `static` functions visible to the linker? It may well be that they are dealt with by the compiler and that the linker never even see them.

Comment: If you just define the function but don't use it, it doesn't necessarily go anywhere: it may be dropped on the spot by the compiler. If you use it exactly once, chances are that it's going to be inlined  by the compiler *no matter how long it is*, and no free standing version will be compiled just as above. The point is, when you say `static`, the compiler already knows about *all* uses of the function, and can optimize accordingly.

Comment: What do you think `__func__` means? You must know, since it is present in your C code.

Comment: @Lundin but it may be obscured by some macro of some library etc...

Comment: @cmaster, I think you are right, I only use the static function once, and it should be inlined by the compiler. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The symbols you observe do not point to the function, but to the *names* of the functions. You probably use the macro `__func__` inside these static functions, which leads to creation of those symbols.

For example:

```
printf("%s: %s\n", __func__, somemsg);
```

would lead to the creation of those symbols. It may be obscured by a macro like

```
#define FUNC_ENTRY printf("%s entered\n", __func__);
```

or similar, so it might not be directly visible.

The static functions themselves are usually not visible in the symbol table since they cannot be linked externally.

Comment: What confused me is that the .o file doesn't contain symbol of the static function. Now I think @cmaster is right: as the static function is used only once, it is inlined by the compiler.

Comment: @shijunzhao This doesn't matter, the name is stored in such symbols regardless what happens with the function.

Comment: @shijunzhao This has absolutely nothing to do with static or inlining, as shown in this answer. `__func__` generates text strings in `.rodata` and that's what you see, simple as that.

Comment: HI, @Ctx you say that the static functions are usually not visible in the symbol table, then are they usually inlined?

Comment: @shijunzhao This is on  the disposition of the compiler and has nothing to do with the symbol table. A compiler might even choose to inline a non-static function _and_ provide a globally visible instance of it additionally. This depends on the size of the code of this function, the number of usages and the optimization parameters.

Comment: Static functions are typically visible, however marked as local. In this case, since ffunction-sections option is provided, each function is stored in a separate section. 
With that flag, linker performs dead function elimination on those functions, and aggregates all remaining sections into .text (with static functions marked as local).